# How can I remove a specific item from an array in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi

I'm writing a multiplatform application in RAD 10.3.3 and i have an array manipulation problem

```
type
    Tsex = (F,M);

    Tcheckup = record
        values : array of Tvalue;
        name: string;
        case integer of
            0 : (minV : array[F..M] of word;
                 maxV : array[F..M] of word;
                 monada : byte;);
            1 : (male : boolean);
        end;
var deiktes    : array of Tcheckup;
.....
// here i'm filling array "deiktes" with right values

....
// 0 < j  < length(deiktes)
//here i try to delete the item j, so i move all the following one step up
// to overwrite the j item

move(deiktes[j+1],deiktes[j],(length(deiktes)-1-j)*sizeof(TCheckUp)); (1)
// and then decrease the length of the array
setLength(deiktes,length(deiktes)-1); (2)
```

In debug mode i can see that the array "values" is as must it be after deletion.
But continuing the execution the last item has random values in the array "values" (but right value in the string "name")
I suppose that either (1) or (2) functions free the pointer of the array "values" so, when the app needs to store something else, it uses the freed pointer's memory.
If so, what can i do to avoid this please?

Comment: If you want to delete an item, call the Delete function. That will do the job more simply and also doesn't suffer from the defect of your code which operates on a managed type without respecting reference counting.

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to use a `TList<TCheckup>` instead.

Comment: @david-heffernan
but "deiktes" is a dynamic array of Tcheckup record. It hasn't any delete function

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand 
seems quite appropriate. I will give it a try. Is it certain that this way I will not have a problem with the dynamic table "values" when I delete a member of the list? Should I not do setlength (values, 0) first?
However, I still do not understand why the way I do it creates a problem. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: @Jim It's not a method of the array. It's a function called Delete. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Delete

Comment: And the problem is what I said. This is a managed type and you have to let the compiler handle the reference counting, but memory copy subverts that. I'm sure I can find a duplicate to close the question against.

Comment: @ David Heffernan
Thanks. system.delete works fine
How can I upvote your answer ?

Comment: There is no answer here to upvote because this is a duplicate.